# Cannot install MPLAB IDE X from the terminal - silently exits

Tags: 12.04, binary

I have a file, and terminal won't run it.  I don't understand why.  There are a number of files in directory, but the binaries are the only ones that fail.  help?  I use this program for my work, and without it I'm in a world of un-productivity.  I just did a clean install of 12.04.  Am I missing a vital package?  Why are there no errors, is it the binary itself?  They are marked as executable.

```
mantra@Mantra:~$ cd iambuff/mplab\ 1.2\ full\ package/
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ ls
mplabc18-v3.40-linux-full-installer.run  picc-9.83-linux.run
mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run     picc-9.83-linux.zip
picc-18-9.80.11162-linux.run             xc8-v1.00-linux.run
PICC_18_9_80_linux_run.zip
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ sudo ./mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run 
[sudo] password for mantra: 
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ sudo ./mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run -v
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$
```

In response to the first response to my question, here is the -lh output and the echo.  Thanks.

```
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ ls -lh
total 712M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mantra mantra  71M Jun  1 01:48 mplabc18-v3.40-linux-full-installer.run
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mantra mantra 230M Jun  1 01:11 mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mantra mantra 123M Sep 26  2011 picc-18-9.80.11162-linux.run
-rw-r--r-- 1 mantra mantra 122M Jun  1 02:10 PICC_18_9_80_linux_run.zip
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mantra mantra  17M Sep 21  2011 picc-9.83-linux.run
-rw-r--r-- 1 mantra mantra  17M Jun  1 02:08 picc-9.83-linux.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mantra mantra 136M Jun  1 02:04 xc8-v1.00-linux.run
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ sudo ./mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run 
[sudo] password for mantra: 
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$
```

In response to the third post. The echo command yields 127?

```
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ ./mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run 
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$ echo $?
127
mantra@Mantra:~/iambuff/mplab 1.2 full package$
```

Comment: "ls -lh" output will be more helpful, as it will show the file modes for each file as well. Also, after you run the program and it exits giving you back control of the terminal, what does "echo $?" output if you run it?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I put the answer in the original post.

Comment: I think the binary is being run, but it is silently exiting (if it was a permission problem it would say "permission denied"). Are you sure you need to run this with sudo? You should probably be able to install programs into your home directory.

Comment: You need to run "echo $?" and not "echo $". The question mark is literal there, and is a special variable, which holds the exit code of the last run program. Is it required to run the program with sudo? You should just run it as your normal user.

Comment: Thank you pablomme and dobey.  I tried it without the super, and published the echo output.

Comment: Just add sudo infront of ./

Comment: Oh you already tried sudo ,Then probably the cause is missing of libraries which is needed to execute that file , BTW can you provide download link for that file :)

Comment: What type of file is it? `file ./mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The installer requires 32-bit libraries not present by default on a 64-bit system

MPLAB IDE may be 32/64-bit, but it's **installer** is 32-bit only and won't run by default on a 64-bit Ubuntu installation. To get the minimal 32-bit libraries it needs to run, please do

`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`

This will let the installer run, but if you get any more problems, simply install the full 32-bit library set with `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`.

---

#### How?

I downloaded the MPLAB IDE installer to figure this out.

The last two lines of `strace ./mplabx-ide-v1.20-linux-installer.run` are revealing:

```
open("/lib/ld-linux.so.2", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
_exit(127)                              = ?
```

That file is only present on 32-bit installations, or if you've installed the 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system.

Comment: you sir, are very talented.  Or miss, whatever you may be.

Comment: @Pentax : Thank you, dear sir (or madam). Please accept the answer (tick mark on left) in that case so the question is marked as "answered".